# Rails equivalent of setInterval?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's a piece of code (based on an example at W3Schools) that uses Javascript to update a page on a regular basis:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timer test</title>
  <script>
  var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);

  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();  
    document.getElementById("timeNow").innerHTML =  d.toLocaleTimeString();   
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
  <h1>The time now is <span id="timeNow"></span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there an equivalent in pure Ruby/Rails that would update the "timeNow" span element on a regular schedule?

Comment: ... No? You'd need to do something with websockets or SocketIO etc. in order to get a push notification from a server app.

Comment: or he could make a regular ajax request, depending on a situation tho as the case is quite theoretical

Comment: True, but then I might as well just use the code I pasted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ruby/Rails** are **server side** languages and have no effect on the client. You would need to use **client side** languages or send a notification to the client telling it to update, using something like [SocketIO](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that little detail. It looks like I'll have to set up some kind of RESTful API to produce the data I want and drop some code similar to the above into my page to query the API.